# how to generate 3 words using random class

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, random

I am given a multi-array (based on page, paragraph, and line number chosen randomly) that tells a story. I need to generate a password containing 3 words taken randomly from the array. Rules have to be given to creating the password (eg: it must be 10 characters long, no repetition of the same word);

This is for Java. (step 1)The password must be composed of 3 words (step 2) page, paragraph and line number are chosen randomly and must use random class to generate random numbers using nextInt().  (step 3) Used split() to separate each word in the random string. (step 4) Make sure to choose a random word from array in step 3. (step 5) create restrictions for the password.

I created an if-else statement for the restriction.
If the rule(s) is not followed, the program must always go back to (step 2)

```
 import java.util.Random;

 public class passGen {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Random r=new Random();

int pageNum = r.nextInt(story.length);
    int paraNum = r.nextInt(story.length);
    int lineNum = r.nextInt(story.length);

    System.out.print("Password = ");

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {

        String sentence = story[pageNum][paraNum][lineNum]; // story is the array given
        String[] string = sentence.split(" ");  
        int index = new Random().nextInt(string.length);            
        String randomWord = string[index];

        if (randomWord.equals("a") || randomWord.contains("\n")) {
        }
        else 
            System.out.print(randomWord);

    }
      }
    }
```

Let's say the random generator picks a random sentence from the array:
story[0][1][5] gives "The boy is riding on a bicycle\n". Using split() and then randomly selecting the word based on its index, it picks the random word "bicycle\n". I made a rule that if it picks a word with new line ('\n') it must go back to the step where it generates random numbers again and gives me a new array and finds me a new random word until it finds me a word that doesn't have \n. For example, let's say story[0][1][6] is "He is having fun."

I expected the output to print one password with 3 random words combined all the time.

```
         password =  boyfun.having   // fun. is considered as one word with the period.
```

but there were cases that when it failed, it only prints out words that passed the restriction ('\n'). Sometimes it would print 1 word, or 2 words, or it will give an error when I run the program.

```
password = ridingfun

password = boy 

Password = Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Assign3Q1.main(passGen.java:123)

// line 123 happens is the String sentence = story[pageNum][paraNum][lineNum];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean but I'm pretty sure you will hit an out of bounds eventually using your random number generator.

If your story has a length of 10, nextInt can select 10 as it is inclusive of the int you pass it. Therefore if you end up with a 10 and then do story[10] you will get an out of bounds as index starts at 0.

I suggest

```
r.nextInt(story.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in:

```
int pageNum = r.nextInt(story.length);
int paraNum = r.nextInt(story.length);
int lineNum = r.nextInt(story.length);
```

The number of paragraphs depends on the page, and the number of lines depends on the page and paragraph. I suspect what you want is:

```
int pageNum = r.nextInt(story.length);
int paraNum = r.nextInt(story[pageNum].length);
int lineNum = r.nextInt(story[pageNum][paraNum].length);
```

With respect to finding three words that pass your criteria, before concatenating them, you could use streams to achieve this rather than your for loop. At the moment words that don't satisfy your criteria will be just quietly ignored:

```
Stream.generate(this::randomWord)
    .filter(w -> !w.contains("\n"))
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Otherwise you'll need a counter for number of words:

```
int wordsRequired = 3;
while (wordsRequired > 0) {
    String randomWord = ...;
    if (!randomWord.contains("\n")) {
        System.print...
        randomWord--);
    }
}
```

Also note that you can automatically remove the newlines by using `split("\\s")`. That will split on any whitespace (rather than just spaces) which includes newlines and tabs.

Comment: Hi, I notice in the bottom program there "..." in several areas. What is supposed to go there?